# What is an invisible sheet named "D%$&01_DevSheet" doing in an Excel OOXML workbook?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm writing a program to read some data from an OOXML Excel Workbook using Apache POI that was provided to me as example input data.  There is a strange sheet named `D%$&01_DevSheet` at the end.  It is full of formula cells with weird formulas that reference most of the other sheets in the workbook.  Here is an example of one of the cells:

```
'Horizontal Agreements'!S15+"8I/!%4\"
```

It is also not visible when the worksheet is opened in Excel.

I've never run across such a sheet before.  It looks like some kind of internal Excel structure. Google searches for `"D%$&01_DevSheet"` and `"excel" "DevSheet"` have turned up nothing useful.

This sheet is not present in any test workbooks I've created.  However, I'm not much of an Excel user and I did not exhaustively try all Excel features.

At this point, I'm going to hard code a rule that excludes sheets ending in `_DevSheet` from processing.  However, since this stuff is turning up in my input, I think I should understand and handle it properly, so I have some basic questions:

1. What does Excel use sheets like `D%$&01_DevSheet` for?
2. What user actions cause them to be created?
3. Are they named regularly?
4. What is the most reliable way of detecting sheets like this Apache POI?

Comment: Regarding "not visible when opened in Excel": possibly the sheet is "VeryHidden". https://stackoverflow.com/q/72987885/3654325 or google Excel xlSheetVeryHidden

Answer (score 2):

Normally Excel does not use such a sheet, so it seems to be added by some specific application or tool that was used to create this Excel workbook. It seems the developer of the application stores formulas and other things in a separate sheet for separation from the user-visible content.

So likely you will need to contact/research whichever application provided this file and get more information about this sheet from there.

You can probably only exclude these sheet by name as you already did.